# Selecting only required fields from DB in laravel using with()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

```
foreach(Book::with('author')->get() as $book)
{ 
   echo $book->author->name;
}
```

Above loop is like below two queries:

```
select * from books

select * from authors where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)
```

If i want to select only required fields like below query using laravel 5.6, how can I do it?

```
select book_name, book_description from books

select author_name from authors where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
Book::with('author:id,author_name')->get(['book_name', 'book_description', 'author_id']);
```

Comment: Thanks for help, Dear!

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach(Book::with('author' => function($query){ $query->select('id', 'author_name'); })->select('book_name', 'book_description')->get() as $book)
{ 
   echo $book->author->name;
}
```